# SQL Server insert value with leading whitespace

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a `C#` program that reads from a file and inserts the data into fields in my database.

An issue I'm having is that it's not inserting data when the value starts with a leading space. The datatype is `NCHAR`. for example, when i try to read and insert `" 2"`, nothing inserts into that field even though it's mapped properly. Is there a way around this?

```
table2_1.MONTHS_DOWN_PAY = mylines02[i].Substring(58, 2).Trim();
```

value it's grabbing from text file: " 0"

SQL field: `MONTHS_DOWN_PAY nchar(2) NULL`

Comment: If you try to write the value of mylines02[i].Substring(58,2).Trim(); to a log file, what do you get? Also, can you give some sample data? I'd be interested in knowing what mylines02[0] looks like.

Comment: What are the exact character values in that string? `Trim()` should have removed the whitespace already...

Comment: the length of the field is 2 characters, and the length of the entire line in the file is like 107. sometimes the field only contains 1 character however, in which case the space has to be leading.

Comment: @Cameron is right. Debug, copy and paste this string to any hexeditor and check if this is really a whitespace.

Comment: Have you tried laying this off in your insert statement? something like RTRIM(LTRIM(@param))

Answer (score 0):

the c# Trim() should remove all leading and trailing white spaces. Could be a unicode character not displaying properly on your text editor.